# Parsing span with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to parse through some website trying to find 'span' which is inside a div tag and a class_. Span is in a particular class  if equal to string e.g 'line'  then it return actual link of the website.

error message that I am getting:

> line 28, in 
>       soup = BeautifulSoup(url_html,"html.parser") line 245, in **init**
>       elif len(markup) <= 256 and ( TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

contents = []

def condition_check():
    for sp in soup.find("div",class_='-vDIg'):
        check = sp.span
        if check in ['Line','LINE ID',]:
            return link


filename = 'link_business_filter.csv'

with(open(filename,'rt')) as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)

    for row in data:
        links = row[0]
        contents.append(links)



for link in contents:
    url_html = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_html,"html.parser")
    con_fltr = condition_check()
    print(con_fltr)
```

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(url_html.text,"html.parser")`?

Comment: Post that html snippet too, and What target value you specifically want

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your object initialisation. You should probably check the return type of `requests.get()`. I think to get the actual HTML representation you need to do `url_html.content` or something like that. Read the documentation for `requests`.

Comment: @Rakesh after adding soup = BeautifulSoup(url_html.text,"html.parser") line 30, in <module>
    con_fltr = condition_check()   in condition_check
    for sp in soup.find("div",class_="-vDIg"):

Comment: Also, I suggest you put `soup` as an input argument for `condition_check`.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated I added soup = BeautifulSoup(url_html.content,"html.parser") error now I am getting this one >> line 30, in <module> con_fltr = condition_check(),,line 8, in condition_check for sp in soup.find("div",class_="-vDIg"):

Comment: That doesn't say what's the actual error. It only says the location where it occurred. My intuition is that `find` only returns the first element. You need `findAll `to iterate.

Comment: In any case, you seem very green. Are you completely new to programming? If you have no idea what's wrong with your code, start printing out the content and type of the variables you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the Request object to Beautiful Soup, you need to pass the html content like this:

```
for link in contents:
    url_html = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_html.content,"html.parser")
    con_fltr = condition_check()
    print(con_fltr)
```

**url_html --> url_html.content**

Comment: I added   soup = BeautifulSoup(url_html.content,"html.parser") error now I am getting this one >> line 30, in <module>
    con_fltr = condition_check(),,line 8, in condition_check
    for sp in soup.find("div",class_="-vDIg"):

Comment: @BhatOvasQayoom If you are looking for multiple elements in soup.find("div",class_="-vDIg"), change it to soup.find_all("div",class_="-vDIg"). or share the whole stacktrace here